# Adding multiple functions to Cobra packages causes [ (no value) used as value ] compile error

Tags: go

After adding a second subcommand to the Cobra console app, I got the error `(no value) used as value`. Looking up the error, it says that TooManyValues occur. As if I'm attempting to return 2 values instead of one. Which is simple enough, but I'm not sure how that applies to the code I've written. Should I not be adding the functions to the same file as the cobra console code?

Error:

```
go build -o azGoCLI.exe
# azGoCLI/cmd
cmd\blob.go:40:25: DeleteContainer(args[0], args[1]) used as value
```

Much thanks in advance!

```
package cmd

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(mainCmd)
    mainCmd.AddCommand(createContainer)
    mainCmd.AddCommand(deleteContainer)
}

var mainCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "blob",
    Short: "...",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        cmd.Usage()
    },
}

var createContainer = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "create-container [storageAccount] [containerName]",
    Short: "...",
    Args:  cobra.MinimumNArgs(2),
    RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
        return CreateContainer(args[0], args[1])
    },
}

var deleteContainer = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "delete-container [storageAccount] [containerName]",
    Short: "...",
    Args:  cobra.MinimumNArgs(2),
    RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
        return DeleteContainer(args[0], args[1])
    },
}

func CreateContainer(storageaccount, container string) error {

    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Authentication failure: %+v", err)
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    containerClient, err := azblob.NewContainerClient("https://"+storageaccount+".blob.core.windows.net/"+container, cred, nil)

    _, err = containerClient.Create(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return nil
}

func DeleteContainer(storageaccount, container string) {
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Authentication failure: %+v", err)
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    containerClient, err := azblob.NewContainerClient("https://"+storageaccount+".blob.core.windows.net/"+container, cred, nil)

    _, err = containerClient.Delete(ctx, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failure: %+v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. can you provide full error stacktrace?
2. can you try to use `Args:    cobra.ExactArgs(2),` instead of `Args: cobra.MinimumNArgs(2),` in command definitions?

Comment: I'll update it with the full stacktrace and give `cobra.ExactArgs` a try. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, your function

```golang
func DeleteContainer(storageaccount, container string) {
```

doesn't return anything. However you are returninng it here:

```golang
var deleteContainer = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "delete-container [storageAccount] [containerName]",
    Short: "...",
    Args:  cobra.MinimumNArgs(2),
    RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
        return DeleteContainer(args[0], args[1])
    },
}
```

in `RunE` as if it returned an `error`. That is why it's throwing an error.'

Solving this will depend on your use case though as to how you want to handle the error in case `DeleteContainer` errors out

Comment: Not sure why they downvoted, that fixed my issue. :)

My adding a return for the DeleteContainer func and a return nil I was able to resolve the error. Probably not the best solution, but I'm hacking my way thought it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Add a return value for the DeleteContainer function and a return statement.

```
func DeleteContainer(storageaccount, container string) error {
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Authentication failure: %+v", err)
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    containerClient, err := azblob.NewContainerClient("https://"+storageaccount+".blob.core.windows.net/"+container, cred, nil)

    _, err = containerClient.Delete(ctx, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failure: %+v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```